# Applescript how to display a dialog with text and a variable

Tags: variables, text, dialog, applescript, var

I need to display a applescript dialog with text and a number by which i mean the text that it displays would be text and a varible like this `display dialog "Enter spelling" and repeatnum buttons{"done"}` This is the code I have`isplay dialog "How many spellings are there" buttons {"That amount"} default answer ""

```
set amount to text returned of result

set repeatdone to 0

repeat amount times

    repeatdone = repeatdone + 1

    display dialog "enter spelling " and repeatdone buttons {"Ok"} default answer ""

end repeat
```

When I try this it gives me the error cannot make enter spelling into type boolean, Is there anyway to make a applescript dialog display text and a varible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
display dialog "How many spellings are there" buttons {"That amount"} default answer ""
set amount to text returned of result

set repeatdone to 0
repeat amount times
    set repeatdone to repeatdone + 1
    display dialog "enter spelling " & repeatdone buttons {"Ok"} default answer ""
end repeat
```